# How do I add arguments to a subclass in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, subclass, superclass

```
class Wolf:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = 4
class Dog(Wolf):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
fido = Dog(legs = 4, color = "brown")
```

This would spute out an error message. How would I do something like that where I add parameters to the subclass that doesn't pertain to the superclass.

Comment: You could, in Wolf's `init`, add `**kwargs` to the list of the arguments (after `legs`), so that `Wolf` can take the argument but not do anything with it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
class Wolf:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = 4
class Dog(Wolf):
    def __init__(self, legs, color):
        super().__init__(legs)
        self.color = color
fido = Dog(legs=4, color="brown")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from a [tutorial](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python) which explains inheritance and shows how to do this.  You need to call the parent class's **init** function as in this similar example from this tutorial:

```
class Pet(object):

    def __init__(self, name, species):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s is a %s" % (self.name, self.species)


class Dog(Pet):

    def __init__(self, name, chases_cats):
        Pet.__init__(self, name, "Dog")
        self.chases_cats = chases_cats

    def chasesCats(self):
        return self.chases_cats
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how inheritance works. When you inherit from another class, the super-class's parameters are not automatically added to the sub-class's parameter list. You must explicitly accept the desired parameters in your sub-class's constructor and pass them on to the super class's constructor:

```
class Wolf:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = 4

class Dog(Wolf):
    def __init__(self, color, legs):
        super().__init__(legs)
        self.color = color

fido = Dog(legs = 4, color = "brown")
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to pass in the legs argument for `Dog`, and then use `super`:

```
class Wolf:
    def __init__(self, legs):
        self.legs = 4
class Dog(Wolf):
    def __init__(self, color, legs):
        super().__init__(legs)
        self.color = color
fido = Dog(legs = 4, color = "brown")
```